# Is there a better way to test JTree node expanded or not?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I want to find a method like isNodeExpanded() to check if a given JTree node is expanded or not, but I can not find it.

I know I can do this by tracking the node expansion with the TreeExpansionListener.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

JTree.java:

```
 /**
 * Returns true if the node identified by the path is currently expanded,
 * 
 * @param path  the <code>TreePath</code> specifying the node to check
 * @return false if any of the nodes in the node's path are collapsed, 
 *               true if all nodes in the path are expanded
 */
public boolean isExpanded(TreePath path);
```

Beautiful, JavaDoc :-)

The expanded state of a Node is *not* in the `TreeModel` but in the `JTree`.

Comment: Thanks, I overlook the JTree's JavaDoc :-)